# Sustaining highlight

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to highlight a dom object using jquery. I found out a way using `effect` from jquery ui:

```
$('#foo').hover(function(){$('#bar').effect("highlight");});
```

but this takes effect only when the mouse move in/out to `#foo`. I want the effect to sustain during when the mouse is over `#foo`, and get back to before when the mouse leaves. I tried, this:

```
$('#foo').mouseover(function(){$('#bar').effect("highlight");});
```

but still does not work. How can I make the effect sustain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` to add effects to add a class to you element.
Sample:
HTML:

```
<div id="foo">
    <p>Hello world</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#foo').mouseenter(function(){$(this).addClass("highlight");});
$('#foo').mouseleave(function(){$(this).removeClass("highlight");});
```

CSS:

```
.highlight{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Fiddler:
http://jsfiddle.net/2CL7u/

You can also make this effect with pure HTML and CSS like this:
HTML:

```
<div id="foo">
    <p>Hello world</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#foo:hover{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Fiddler:
http://jsfiddle.net/7Qq7n/

Answer (score 0):

You need an interval (using setTimeout) that is toggled on/off

```js
 var hInterval = null;

 $('#foo').on({
   'mouseenter': function(){
      hInterval = setTimeout(function highlight(){
        $('#bar').effect("highlight", function(){ hInterval = setTimeout(highlight, 100); });
      }, 100);
   },
   'mouseleave': function(){
      clearTimeout(hInterval);
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `animation` to save the UI color transfer animation when changing between colors.

```
$('#foo').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        backgroundColor: "#ffff99"
    },'fast');
});

$('#foo').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        backgroundColor: "#ffffff"
    },'fast');
});
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qE9gh/)

[jq UI color animation demo](http://jqueryui.com/animate/)